# ReferenceError: undefinedcreateProvider is not defined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a problem with my react project.
after 5 months of developing this project, I get this error a lot.
`undefinedcreateProvider is not defined`
 and I have to reinstall node_modules. But I get this error again after a few changes in the project.
I don't know why this error appears!

[image: undefinedcreateProvider is not defined]

Comment: *I don't know why this error appears* - so we don't. You're the only person who can debug it. You can click on locations in callstack to check what happens. Other users can't. You can set up a breakpoint. Other users can't. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is a requirement for questions on SO. From how `createProvider` is used in Redux codebase it's hard to imagine where a thing like `undefinedcreateProvider` could come from.

Comment: @estus Yeah, that's right. But I tried everything you said before. I found another solution to fix this problem. Deleting .cache folder in node_module folder fixed this issue. but I get it after few changes again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and also important to notice that I use [hard-source-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/mzgoddard/hard-source-webpack-plugin). There are two ways to solve this problem (at least for me):

1. Downgrade webpack to v4.18.1; or
2. Disable `hard-source-webpack-plugin` in webpack config, though the webpack builds are slower now.

Deleting `.cache` folder didn't help me.

Comment: That's right! I'll disable `hard-source-webpack-plugin`